# Откуда взялся метод? getContent();

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Друзья, добрый день...читай книгу Spring Boot 2022..и тут появляется метод .getContent() в котором должен быть аргумент (у автора по книге он не выдает ошибку), а меня  требует аргумент..тем более не понятно, где он взял метод.

```
package tacos.web.api;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import tacos.Taco;
import tacos.data.TacoRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/api/tacos",                      // <1>
                produces="application/json")
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://tacocloud:8080")        // <2>
public class TacoController {
  private TacoRepository tacoRepo;

  public TacoController(TacoRepository tacoRepo) {
    this.tacoRepo = tacoRepo;
  }

  @GetMapping(params="recent")
  public Iterable<Taco> recentTacos() {                 //<3>
    PageRequest page = PageRequest.of(
            0, 12, Sort.by("createdAt").descending());
    return tacoRepo.findAll(page).getContent();
  }

  @PostMapping(consumes="application/json")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public Taco postTaco(@RequestBody Taco taco) {
    return tacoRepo.save(taco);
  }

  @GetMapping("/{id}")
  public Optional<Taco> tacoById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    return tacoRepo.findById(id);
  }

  /*
  @GetMapping("/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<Taco> tacoById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Optional<Taco> optTaco = tacoRepo.findById(id);
    if (optTaco.isPresent()) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(optTaco.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }
  */

}
```

Comment: В findAll, можно передать несколько аргуметнов, в том числе Pageable. В данном случае, в метод findAll  передают одну из реализаций Pageable, поэтому получают Page на выходе, у Page есть поле content, хранящее List<Entity>.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно `TacoRepository` расширяет стандартный интерфейс `PagingAndSortingRepository`, в котором содержится метод [`findAll(Pageable pageable)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-), который возвращает страницу [`Page<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html):

> [`Page<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) `findAll(Pageable pageable)`
> Returns a [`Page`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) of entities meeting the paging restriction provided in the `Pageable` object.
> Parameters:
> pageable - the pageable to request a paged result, can be `Pageable.unpaged()`, must not be null.
> Returns:
> a page of entities

Соответственно, интерфейс `Page` заимствует метод [`getContent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html#getContent--) из своего родительского интерфейса `Slice`:

> `List<T> getContent()`
> Returns the page content as List.

Comment: По книге там interface TacoRepository  наследует CrudRepository<Taco, Long>

Comment: Есть ссылка на книгу/гитхаб с кодом из книги?

Comment: https://github.com/habuma/spring-in-action-6-samples/blob/main/ch06/taco-cloud/src/main/java/tacos/data/TacoRepository.java

Comment: https://github.com/habuma/spring-in-action-6-samples/blob/main/ch07/tacocloud-api/src/main/java/tacos/web/api/TacoController.java